# What's the geometric mean for (0,1)?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, education

Someone asked me :what's the geometric mean for (0,1)

then I wrote this:

$$\mu=\sqrt[n]{x_0x_1x_2...x_n}\\ 
\\n \to \infty  \\\mu=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n-1}{n}.\frac{n-2}{n}...\frac{n-(n-1)}{n}}\\ \ln \mu=\frac{1}{n} \ln(\frac{n-1}{n}.\frac{n-2}{n}...\frac{n-(n-1)}{n})=\\ 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ln \frac{n-i}{n}=\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ln(1-\frac{i}{n})=\\
\int_{0}^{1}\ln(1-x)dx=\\(1-x)\ln(1-x)-x=-1\\ \to \mu=e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$$ 
Am I right ?

Is it possible to find geometric mean for [0,1]

thanks in advaced .

Comment: Isn't $\mu=0$ when you wrote $\mu=$.

Comment: No matter what you are doing, you can't have a term $\frac{n-n}{n}$ in the product since it makes the product exactly zero every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though I would say the geometric mean across the interval $(0,1]$ was $$\exp\left(\int_0^1 \log_e(x)\,dx \right) =\exp\left(\lim_{b\to 0+}\left[x\log_e(x)-x \right]_b^1 \right) = \exp\left(-1 \right) = \dfrac{1}{e}$$